# How do I regist JS with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controls

I want build a MVC Custom Control.

Now I have a problem.

My control has a file of js  and a file of css.

I only want the page which used the control load the js and the css

and if i use this control maney times the js and css load once.

I know we can do like this in web form:
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(..), "Assembly.MyScript.js");

but how can i do this in mvc??

there are two problem:

1.I want build a control to use in my project just like this **@html.mycontrol()** and the person who use it do not care any other(do not care if js or css load)

2.this control may use in other project.so i do not want the the other project know how to get the controls js or css(i Write this control in class liberary)

Answer (score 0):

You control your includes through BundleConfig in MVC.

Normally, all bundles are loaded in the _Layout.cshtml document, like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

You can make a custom bundle in the BundleConfig.cs file like this:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/nameOfBundle").Include(
                    "~/pathToFile"));
```

And then you just load the bundle in the file you need them in, instead of in the Layout.cshtml file.

Comment: I am sorry to answer so late. my problem is following:1.I want build a control to use in my project just like this **@html.mycontrol()** and the person who use it do not care any other(do not care if js or css load) 2.this control may use in other project.so i do not want the the other project know how to get the controls js or css

Comment: I think you might be refering to custom HTML helpers. You can read this article about exactly that:http://blogs.technet.com/b/sateesh-arveti/archive/2013/09/06/custom-html-helper-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**[Return Javascript from MVC COntroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541336/can-i-return-javascript-from-mvc-controller-to-view-via-ajax-request)**

**[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript.aspx)**

**Example:**

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 999999)]
public virtual JavaScriptResult Global()
{
var script = string.Format(@"
MaxNotificaitonsToShow = {0};
ItemsPerPage = 25;",
GlobalSettings.MaxNotificaitonsToShow);
return JavaScript(script);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to answer so late. my problem is following:1.I want build a control to use in my project just like this **@html.mycontrol()** and the person who use it do not care any other(do not care if js or css load) 2.this control may use in other project.so i do not want the the other project know how to get the controls js or css

Comment: **first**: I want use razor code like this **@html.mycontrol()** ,when I use the code ,the js and css load automatic, do not need any other code. **second**:I want this control write in class liberary ,and can use in anywhere.

Comment: **first question** the css and js only load when i use **@html.mycontrol()**  and when i use this **@html.mycontrol()** more than one time ,the share css and js only load once.  **seconde question** how to use this control in any other project