# Return Javascript in c# mvc action replaces view with plain text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

My code which was working earlier with a Action returning Javascript has suddenly stopped working.

My view shows a jquery dialog and within that dialog when user clicks save button control goes to mvc post which returns

```
 return JavaScript("OnCreateSuccess('some value')");
```

Earlier the javascript method use to execute.. now instead, the browser view is replaced with text

OnCreateSuccess('some value');

I know its not the good way of passing information but I inherited this code like it is.

Comment: are you calling this action using AJAX call ?? return Javascript only works with that. Check more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541336/can-i-return-javascript-from-mvc-controller-to-view-via-ajax-request

Comment: unfortunately it's using $('#form').submit(); I'm working on alternative to replace this to make ajax post

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the Action to return JSON and used Ajax call and jquery callback to handle the returned values.

Thanks @Deep